# Vertical-Align not working email

Tags: css, html

I'm coding emails using adobe CRM and HTML 5 and CSS.
I have a problem with Vertical-Align:Middle it's working fine in Outlook but when forward email to gmail it's not working it's like it adds a space in my image table.
this my code

```
table
{
border-spacing : 0;
border-collapse : collapse;
margin: 0 auto;
}
td
{
padding: 0; 
}

      <table width="680" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <img alt="" src="1.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
               <tr>
                  <td><img alt="" src="2.png" style="vertical-align:middle;"></td>
                  <td>

          <img alt=""  src="3.png" style="vertical-align:middle;"></td>
                  <td>
          <img alt="" src="4.png" style="vertical-align:middle;"></td>
                  <td>

          <img alt="" src="5.png"style="vertical-align:middle;"></td>
                  <td>
          <img alt="" src="6.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">
          </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <img alt="" src="7.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">

            </table>
```

Dont know why it's not working for Gmail and it's working fine for Outlook...
Can someone help me please ? 
thanks

Comment: does it happen when you send the mail directly to gmail? Forwarding emails srews up the html most of the time.

Comment: Second what Manuel said. I run into this annoying issue often when building email templates, forwarding them can completely break formatting.

Comment: Can't test it by sending it directly to gmail , but when i inspect the code in Gmail and i look for my Vertical-Align i cant see them when i add them , it works fine , it's like Gmail Cant read them any ideas ?

Comment: Confirm for me, this is the lines you want to be centered? `<img alt="" src="1.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">`

Comment: it's   second table with image 2 3 4 5 6 and the last table with image 7 i just dont want the space between tables in Gmail